# why ruby inject method is not returning the sum inside a method

Tags: ruby

I was practicing ruby inject method and found one strange output:

```
def adding(*num)
  res = num.inject{|sum,n| sum + n}
  puts "sum:::::::::::::::::::#{res.inspect}"
  puts "sum:::::::::::::::::::#{res.class}"
end

adding ([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Output:

```
sum:::::::::::::::::::[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum:::::::::::::::::::Array
```

While when we do:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].inject{|sum,n| sum + n}
```

Output:

```
15
```

Why this strange output? In method call, adding([1,2,3,4,5]), it should also return 15.

What is the reason for this strange output?

Comment: `sum + n` is sufficient since re-assigning to `sum` is pointless, that's ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num` is not what you think it is.

```
def adding(*num)
  num # => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
end

adding([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Either don't do the splat

```
def adding(num)
```

or pass numbers separately

```
adding(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Yes, you might want to revisit your past questions too. :)

Answer (score 2):

To make a method like this that acceps either an array or an in-line list of numbers:

```
def adding(*num)
  num.flatten.inject { |sum,n| sum + n }
end
```

The `*num` notation means that arguments are put into an array even if they're *already* an array, leading to inadvertent nesting.

Now this will work when called either of these ways:

```
adding(1, 2, 3)
adding([ 1, 2, 3 ])
```

It will also handle crazy stuff like:

```
adding([ [ 1 ], [ [ 2 ], [ [ 3 ] ] ] ])
```

That's because `flatten` will crunch down and eliminate any nested structures.